# IntelliJ Idea and Java EE Development / Deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea and had some, homemade i guess, problems while deploying.

In Eclipse usually my (main-) project contains 4 subprojects:

- EAR
- EJB
- Shared (with JPA Entities, JPA Facet and so on...)
- WEB (JSF, REST)

I know that JetBrains way of organizing is another. So i create a new Project and check all desired technologies i need (EJB, Web, CDI for example). When i try to deploy the project there is as cdi ambigious error, because the class is in the EJB artifact and also in the Web artifact. So my stupid way of thinking was, to delete the compile output from the web artifact, but now the files are not accessible in the Web-Project anymore (CNFE while calling).

So please, what is the correct doing if i'm trying to develop a project with EJBs, JPA, Web (JSF, REST). That could not be so hard and i'm going insane ;). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guten Abend,

I think you should allow to build your project from the command line. I use IntelliJ for large projects and I always make sure that I can build the thing from the commandline with a `mvn clean install` since it is sometimes needed and good not to depend on an IDE. I recommend that you divide your projects into the subprojects that you mention and make a `pom.xml` for each project and put the source into source control e.g. subversion. Then you will be able to checkout the project from subversion and it will load up neatly in IntelliJ iff you got it all configured right.

So if you haven't already, consider using Maven and Subversion (or some other VCS) for your projects and it will simplify your work.

If you provide more details about specific files and specific error messages we can help you more to move forward, and these were my general recommendations.

My setup in IntelliJ that builds a large project from several subprojects looks like the following.

[image]

When done this way, I can rebuild individual subproject without being forced to rebuild the entire thing just because of one small change. And I also can build everything from the commandline using the maven command `mvn clean install`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that mean, you'll need a single instance of IntelliJ for each project?

Comment: @VWeber You can use subprojects to a project so that many `pom.xml` builds a large project for you. I'm updating the answer so that you can have a more detailed look. I think it's good to be able to built everything with maven using the command `mvn clean install` which also can be done in IntelliJ but then it's more effective to build only the subproject that is changed, building a large project can take several minutes so you only want to rebuild what you changed.

Comment: @NiklasinStockholm I'd like to see you other german skills,too.